# What is wrong with my e-commerce tracking with the new API?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics.js

I have already enabled e-commerce for the website i am working on. I cannot figure it out. The following is the snippet at the end of my thank you page:

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-HIDE_ME');
    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'EUR');


     ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '64807', // Transaction ID. Required.
    'affiliation': 'my company',// Affiliation or store name.
    'revenue': '117,00',// Grand Total.
    'shipping': '0', // Shipping.
    'tax': '0'// Tax.
    });

 ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '64807',// Transaction ID. Required.
    'name': 'Sleeping Beauty Musical 1',  // Product name. Required.
    'sku': 'Sleeping Beauty', // SKU/code.
    'category': 'muziektheater', // Category or variation.
    'price': '19,00', // Unit price.
    'quantity': '1'// Quantity.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '64807', // Transaction ID. Required.
    'name': 'Sleeping Beauty Musical 2',  // Product name. Required.
    'sku': 'Sleeping Beauty', // SKU/code.
    'category': 'muziektheater',// Category or variation.
    'price': '16,00',// Unit price.
    'quantity': '1' // Quantity.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '64807',  // Transaction ID. Required.
    'name': 'The Lion King Musical',  // Product name. Required.
    'sku': 'Lion King',  // SKU/code.
    'category': 'dans', // Category or variation.
    'price': '41,00', // Unit price.
    'quantity': '2' // Quantity.
    });


 ga('ecommerce:send');
```

### update

thanks yahelc for editing my code. I found that i have to turn on universal for the clients website. but the client is already using the old google analytics and i am not sure how to turn on both.....ga.js and analytics.js..........

Answer (score 0):

You can run both ga.js and analytics.js simultaneously, but you need create the GA profile as a Universal Analytics profile FIRST (you can't update it after it's been created).